# How to get process id of other endpoint in inter-process communication

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, ipc

Using Win32 C++ API, I would like to known which [IPC method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), allows any end-point in a multi-process communication, to get the PID or HANDLE of the process which it is communicating with. In other words, if process A gets a message from process B:

- Can A know that B sent the message, without B (directly) giving any hint about it inside the message which was sent? How?
- **REQUIREMENT:** PID of B cannot be sent to A inside an IPC message.

The purpose of the communication is a simple remote procedure call. However, I don't want processes on remote systems/hosts calling the procedures offered by process running on the local host.

Of course I have found the [RPC documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I'm wondering if there are better ways than RPC of achieving what I want. Or, if you think RPC is the way to go, can you please tell me why and if you know of any other good references to learn from other than MSDN?

Comment: What would it help? If the endpoint is on an other computer it will not help you at all.. Also a "handle" is only valid within the same process... Normally you solve this by binding the RPC to "127.0.0.1"...

Comment: I want to get the HANDLE of the other process, in the same way you get the HANDLE via the return value of the `OpenProcess` API. The question was formulated in the sense that there may be another function which returns the HANDLE without requiring a PID, e.g. simply based on a IPC message.

Comment: As I said: HANDLES are process specific! You cannot do anything with a handle from a different process...

Comment: In the example I gave with processes A and B. I don't want the HANDLE (pointer) of B from inside B. I want to get the HANDLE of B, inside A, exactly like I would get it from inside A, if I had the PID of B and made the following call inside A: `HANDLE handleOfB = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pibOfB)`.

Comment: Maybe you do not want to understand it... OpenProcess does NOT get a handle *from* process B; it gets a handle inside Process A (which is valid only in process A) for the pidB! It you are sure that you are on the same computer, why not pass the PID???

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I said in my comment before. I don't want to pass the PID because it can be spoofed. If I could pass the PID. I would not have asked this question at all.

Comment: You also cannt pass a HANDLE; because it is only usefully in the process, which owns this handle... Also I do not understand your goal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement your own RPC with [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780.aspx), you will be able to use [GetNamedPipeClientProcessId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365440.aspx) from the server process, to get the PID of the local end point client process.

EDIT: If you really are after security, First Rule is "you shalt not write your own system".

Comment: This might be an answer regarding the question, but: If there is a security issue, this should be solved with security restrictions and not with PIDs... WHO should the app known which PIDs are valid??? If there is a special priviledge or user, then there is no doubt...

Comment: @JochenKalmbach I know. Just answering the question. Will edit, however.

Comment: There is also a corresponding [`GetNamedPipeServerProcessId ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365446.aspx) function.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restrict the RPC to the local computer only, then you should bind your RPC system to "127.0.0.1". Then only local processes can communication with this port!

Answer (score 1):

I'am not familiar with all the methods,

for `WM_COPYDATA` method you have :

```
wParam
    A handle to the window passing the data.
```

so you can use `GetWindowThreadProcessID` on it, but WM_COPYDATA is for use on single PC

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

To identify who has opened given handle you would have to use some low level tricks, like handle.exe program from SysInternals does (http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic18892.html).

Comment: I did not explicitly mention it, but the processes that I use do not have windows. Therefore, I guess I can't use `GetWindowThreadProcessID` in my case. As far as your other suggestion of handle enumeration is concerned, I'm afraid that a process could release the handle to some shared resource like a file, right after it "sends" the message. Moreover, I want to know the ID of the process who sent the message, and in the case of shared resources you may have more than 2 processes having a handle on the same resource, right?

Comment: If you are doing communication between two processes, then it would be an error to include third process in this communication. That would look like you allow communication with your app, from any other app using file of the same name. If you would use shared memory for IPC, then again you would have to give it some name that would be known to your app and to the second app.

Comment: .... IPC normally starts with some handshaking, this is a moment when processes exchange informations about how this communication will take place, this might include names of files / handles. Bacause of that, I really dont see any reason to check PID of remote app because it can be easily provided using your protocol.

Comment: Also, those methods (from sysinternals) for finding handle owners - I would consider rather for Debugging purposes.

Comment: Of course, you can have a protocol where you indicate the PID, but the problem with that is that a malicious process could indicate some other PID, which is different than its own. That is why I explicitly mentioned in my question that the protocol must not involve sending the PID.

Comment: If you are worring about security, then this is a lot more difficult problem. Malicous app can actually use dll injection to impersonate some other - trusted - process. So even if you will find method to finding out PID, this will not be very secure.

Comment: Sure I realize that DLL injection is possible. However, I just need to know if there is a way to find the PID, regardless of whether a malicious process is sending the message or not. What you are referring to is a much bigger problem.